# How to create a PNG file with text on it?

Tags: ruby

From a Ruby app, I need to dynamically create an image file *in memory*. I'd prefer PNG files so I looked at [chunky_png](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png) first. It'd allow me to manipulate PNG images and do a little drawing on the canvas. It does not allow me to render text as pixels, though.

What's the best way to do that?

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) ([doc](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/)). Note that it may be difficult to install because it requires ImageMagick libraries (unlike `chunky_png` which is pure Ruby).

Once installed, you may use the [`annotate`](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html#annotate) method or the vector drawing module RVG (with the [text method](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/rvg.html#RVG_text) used in the [tutorial](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/rvgtut.html)).

Comment: I hesitated to use RMagick because people said it has memory leaks. Does it?

Comment: I think most people talk about images not being garbage collected as soon as they think it should, and not about real memory leaks. There's a good explanation [here](http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=1374&forum_id=1618).